# Why doesn't TileUpdater.Clear() remove all updates?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm about to schedule quite a few tile updates, and noticed that the .Clear() method doesn't seem to work. It should 'Removes all updates and reverts to its default content as declared in the app's manifest'[(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/Apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdater.clear)

EDIT: Cheeky MS! Under the documentation for that method it says: 'Note: This method does not stop periodic updates'

Say I schedule 3000 updates (not what I will be doing btw!), after calling clear the count is still 3000.

[image]

The same question was asked here: [TileUpdater.Clear() not freeing up notifications quota](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/winappswithnativecode/thread/a8af50ca-ff61-49f9-9b05-72a8956eb969) , and the only recommendation was to manually remove each and one of the updates.

I decided to test how much time that would take by using the StopWatch class, and it took a bit over 11 seconds, 18 seconds with the max amount of scheduled updates at 4096,- so that solution seems a bit crazy.

[image]

Since I wont schedule more than a few days ahead on hourly basis and probably use a background task with a maintenance trigger to add new ones I'll be fine with the removal-loop. But I still hope I'm doing something wrong here and that there is a better solution.

So, do you know why .Clear() doesn't work, and what would the best alternative be?

Here is the code if you want to give this a try:

```
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var updater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
        updater.Clear();
        var test = updater.GetScheduledTileNotifications();

        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        foreach (var update in test)
        {
            updater.RemoveFromSchedule(update);
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        var time = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        notify.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            time.Hours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds,
            time.Milliseconds / 10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++)
        {
            var wide = TileContentFactory.CreateTileWideText09();
            var square = TileContentFactory.CreateTileSquareText04();
            wide.TextHeading.Text = "The heading";

            wide.TextBodyWrap.Text = "The body text for notification: " + i;
            square.TextBodyWrap.Text = "The body text for notification: " + i;

            wide.SquareContent = square;

            var tileNotification = new ScheduledTileNotification(wide.GetXml(), DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(i + 1));
            updater.AddToSchedule(tileNotification);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iris,

Clear only clears the changes to tile.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdater.clear.aspx

StopPeriodicUpdate only cancels scheduled updates but does not remove them.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdater.stopperiodicupdate.aspx

Bottom line is - functionality isn't there. Documentation is not clear / .NET like where Clear would actually mean Clear and not **reset content**. Sad state of affairs but that's all we have

Comment: I know about the StopPeriodicUpdates, but I missed the 'Note  This method does not stop periodic updates'. Really bad naming, Clear() should be SetToDefaultTile(). How annoying. So the loop it is then :( Ah well, thanks for the help here and on twitter mate :)

Comment: no worries.. with WinRT we are back in COM era of bad naming :) all those wonderful .NET conventions seem to have vanished.. One good thing.. at least you don't have to call TileUpdateFactory.CoCreateTileUpdaterForAppEx